# Emulating an on-clickable input form

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

[image]

I'm seeking to emulate the on-clickable input forms that pops up when an user clicks on the blue bar as shown above. My experience with front-end development is limited so I don't know what to call these elements exactly, but let's say they are on-clickable input forms contained in a box, which can lead to other on-clickable forms like the date picker as shown.

How do I do this in Javascript? Preferably with AngularJS, since the app I'm working on uses that. I don't mind using JQuery though.

I'm not looking for detailed step-by-step instructions (which I don't mind), but hints to get me started on cloning these features.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pop-ups you see are going to be HTML elements, probably `<div>`s. The page will use JavaScript to create event listeners on the bars to hide/show them when the bars are clicked/moused over. The "pop-ups" are really just like any other element in the page, but with a higher [Z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) and using [CSS positioning (most likely absolute)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Examples) to make it appear as a pop-up. It also looks like they're using the [CSS arrow trick](http://cssarrowplease.com/) to draw the speech bubble pointer, though it could also be accomplished with images.

If I were to develop this, I'd break it down into stages like this:

1. Get my pop-up into my HTML page, and make sure it's not appearing anywhere.
2. Make it show/hide when I wanted it to (either when the blue bar is clicked, or when the user mouses in/mouses out of the blue bar).
3. Make it show/hide *where* I want it to (near the blue bar)
4. Make it look better (work on the CSS and get the pointer to work properly)
5. Convert that work into a second-level popout. The second level is going to be the exact same technique, but maybe the CSS classes are going to be different so the second bubbles look different and have the pointer at a different position.

Of course, you don't have to develop this functionality yourself. There are also [a number of jQuery plugins](http://jquery-plugins.net/tag/bubble-tip) you could use, as well as [Bootstrap's popover component](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers).

Comment: Your answer is exactly what I need! Thanks!